# Windows Security Log: Mysterious Audits?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and having these log events 10-20 times each day:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SERVER241$
    Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Logon Type:         10

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       administrator
    Account Domain:     SERVER241

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0xf04
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   SERVER241
    Source Network Address: 109.230.245.242
    Source Port:        1341

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      User32 
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

Should i not worry about these?

I had a lot of the same problems with my SQL Server, but i just shut em down for the public in the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host headers probably do nat match the computer name.  This is windows doing the loopback verification to prevent man in the middle attacks.  You can disable (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck) it OR add the host headers to the registry:

1. edit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
2. add a new Multi-String Value named BackConnectionHostNames.
3. modify the new BackConnectionHostNames key in the Value data box, type the CNAME or the DNS alias(es) each on a seperate line
4. reboot

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that's a German hacker on IP address 109.230.245.242 trying to hack into your system via a script!
Just block the IP address. He is going around on the net a lot.

http://www.ip-address-lookup-v4.com/ip/109.230.245.242